# osm2pgsql: select relation member by role

Tags: postgresql

I have a standard postgresql OpenStreetMap database that was filled with data via osm2pgsql. There are different tables for different types (points, lines, polygons, relations) that need to get combined for my specific query:
I want to select all relations with the tags `boundary=administrative` and `admin_level=6`. The results need to be searched for a member with the role `admin_centre`.

Here are my steps by now:

Select member-role list:

```
SELECT unnest(members)
FROM planet_osm_rels
WHERE ARRAY['admin_level','6']<@tags AND ARRAY['boundary','administrative']<@tags;
```

Result for one example:

```
    unnest    
--------------
 n240045827
 admin_centre
 w185481610
 outer
 w191987461
 outer
 w166286278
 outer
 w166290573
 outer
 w65481875
 outer
 w166278211
 outer
 w166278224
 outer
 w166278225
 outer
 w166278227
 outer
 w185148605
 outer
 [...]
```

The `n` stands for nodes, the `w` for ways, followed by the unique id that can be found within the respective table (planet_osm_nodes or planet_osm_line). In this example, the admin_centre is the only node, so we can find members that are nodes with LIKE:

```
SELECT name
FROM planet_osm_point
JOIN (
    SELECT ltrim(member, 'n')::bigint AS osm_id
    FROM (
        SELECT unnest(members) AS member
        FROM planet_osm_rels
        WHERE ARRAY['boundary','administrative']<@tags AND ARRAY['admin_level','6']<@tags) u
    WHERE member LIKE 'n%') x
USING(osm_id);
```

Here my question: It is possible that there are several nodes, but with different roles. How could I manage to get only the node that has the role `admin_centre`? Here it would be `n240045827`.

The result from above should be sufficient for my question without going too deep into detail about the database structure. The solution would be to take every nth and nth-1 element as a 2D array in order to have the mapping between member and role.

<sub>Here is the named relation with its admin_center just for clarification:
https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/62383</sub>

Comment: An interesting question.  Since I am not too familiar with OSM, can you specify the data type for members?  Is it simply a `text[]`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Those members are of type text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to query the name of every admin center looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT way,name FROM planet_osm_point
JOIN (
        WITH numbered AS(
            SELECT row_number() OVER() AS row, entry
            FROM(
                SELECT unnest(members) AS entry
                FROM planet_osm_rels
                WHERE ARRAY['boundary','administrative']<@tags AND ARRAY['admin_level','6']<@tags) AS mylist)
        SELECT ltrim(a.entry,'n')::bigint AS osm_id
        FROM numbered AS a JOIN numbered AS b
        ON a.row = b.row-1 AND b.entry = 'admin_centre'
) x
USING(osm_id);
```

Please note that it could fail when there is an entry starting with "n" that is not a node number. So it would be useful to check with a regular expression like `a.entry ~ '^n[0-9]+'`

edit: Added `DISTINCT` to outer select query, since some cities can be the center of the city district and the countryside district.

Answer (score 0):

If we can make the assumption that the `unnest()` operation will always return a set where a member "id" is listed followed by its role in a single column of `text` entries, then I've written up a quick solution for you.

I made a quick data set as:

```
CREATE TABLE mylist (entry text);

INSERT INTO mylist VALUES
('n240045827'),
('admin_centre'),
('w185481610'),
('outer'),
('w191987461'),
('outer'),
('w166286278'),
('outer'),
('w166290573'),
('outer'),
('w65481875'),
('outer'),
('w166278211'),
('outer'),
('w166278224'),
('outer'),
('w166278225'),
('outer'),
('w166278227'),
('outer'),
('w185148605'),
('outer');
```

Assuming we can return this, then the script

```
WITH numbered AS(
  SELECT row_number() OVER() AS row, entry
  FROM mylist)
  SELECT a.entry
  FROM numbered AS a JOIN numbered AS b
  ON a.row = b.row-1 AND b.entry = 'admin_centre';
```

will return only `n240045827`.

How does it work?  Well, I just took a straightforward approach to assigning order to the returned list by using `row_number() OVER()`.  In this example, I've used a CTE `WITH...` to add the row after the fact, but in your case you could add it into your query like so:

```
...
SELECT ltrim(member, 'n')::bigint AS osm_id
    FROM (
    SELECT row_number() OVER() a AS row, unnest(members) AS member
    FROM planet_osm_rels
...
```

Finally, I simply join this result to itself, comparing one row to the next by its row number, and looking for the `'admin_centre'` text entry.

Here's a **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9dfdd/3)** for testing.

For your perusal:

[Common Table Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html)

[Window Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-window.html)

## Edit

If you want to return **all rows as column pairs**, then use the following approach:

```
WITH numbered AS(
  SELECT row_number() OVER() AS row, entry
  FROM mylist)
  SELECT a.entry, b.entry
  FROM numbered AS a JOIN numbered AS b
  ON a.row = b.row-1 AND a.row%2 = 1;
```

Also, here's a **[SQL Fiddle #2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9dfdd/5)** for testing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Chris! It is working as expected, but I am still fighting to fully understand all steps. In the end, I want to have a full query that contains everything. I will post my results when (and if) I have a solution.

Comment: If you want the full set of results as two columns, then alter the `SELECT a.entry` to `SELECT a.entry, b.entry`, and remove the condition `b.entry = 'admin_centre'`.

Comment: That is not the problem I am thinking about. I would like to concatenate all the single queries to one huge query: First query the list from above, take those results into  your solution in order to find the values, trim the leading `n` and take the results as the query for the actual node table. (Still doing try'n'error)

Comment: Oops, also when removing the `b.entry = 'admin_centre'`, also replace it with `a.row%2 = 1`.  See the SQL Fiddle #2 above in my edit.